# Crystal Reports - Only filter by parameter if it has a value, else return all values

Tags: crystal-reports

How do you return all values if the parameter field is left blank?  This is currently what I have in the selection expert:

```
if not(hasvalue({?parameter})) then true else {Table.Column} = {?parameter}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the 'Optional Prompt' property of the parameter to True:
[image: 'Optional Prompt' Property]

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula instead:

```
(not HasValue({?parameter}) OR {Table.Column} = {?parameter})
```

Using optional parameters in Select Expert formulas can be tricky.  As soon as code is parsed that tries to say the parameter is equal to anything, it throws an error because the parameter has no value.  The If...Then...Else logic still parses the entire block of code, regardless of whether the condition is true or false.  In the formula above, if the parameter has no value in the first statement, the result is True, then the OR is parsed and the rest of the statement is ignored without parsing because it's result won't change the outcome of the formula.